# Traditional keyed mitre joint or using through dowels

Tags: joinery

Looking to build some overhead cabinets in a van. These will be made from plywood probably 3/8" unless I can get away with thinner.

Ideally I would like to use finger joints, but without a table saw I'm stuck. However I could use a router.

I've seen a lot of videos on keyed mitred joints, the ones that go all the way through. Where you get that nice contrast of wood.

Then I've seen similar joints but made with through dowels. I was looking at one key per 2" of travel along the edge and maybe something similar with the dowels.

What are your thoughts with regard to ease and strength with these options?

Comment: It's going to be more difficult to do a dowel-pinned miter joint in 3/8" (or thinner) plywood. Splines will be easier to pull off.

Comment: *"I was looking at one spline per 2" of travel along the edge"* Even before I read you don't have a table saw I was afraid you were not going to be referring to splines given the prevalence of this...... I think what you're referring to are keys, is that correct? Despite all the newer content that calls them splines (including from sources that used to know better!) splines are splines and keys are keys. As a mnemonic I coined a couple of years says, *splines are in line, keys kross.* :-) Anyway, terminology aside, this is a no-brainer. Dowels are easier, much faster to do, and waaay stronger.

Comment: @gnicko, huh? I've used dowel reinforcement on stock as thin as 6mm / 1/4" many many times. This is through-dowelling, the drilling is a snap as there's no post-drilling alignment to worry about. The 'secret' is just to use appropriately thin dowels of course, and to dovetail some or all of them (although that's worth doing on all through-dowelling to be fair).

Comment: @Graphus yes sir you are so correct. I noticed after posting this a picture stating the difference. Being new to the forum I wasn't to sure if I could edit it.

Comment: @Graphus seriously, dovetail the dowels. How would I do that? Do you have a video on YouTube to share so I know exactly what you mean. Only because the ones I have seen looks like fiddly work.

Comment: I'll add a formal Answer, which will cover many more details.

Comment: *"I'm not familiar with this type of forum*" This is a very timely comment! I popped in to mention something I just thought of! So first, SE isn't a forum, it's wrong to think of it that way, it's strictly a question-and-answer venue, designed to try to provide good that one on-point Answer (canonical if possible) to a focussed query. The thing I was going to say is if you'd like to get more into discussions about options, be able to spitball ideas and get feedback from multiple people that's exactly what a conventional forum is perfect for. Plus if you choose your forum wisely..... [contd]

Comment: ....(or forum**s**, absolutely no need to limit yourself to just one) the pool of respondents will be much larger than here, because we're pretty quiet here now sadly. Plus most of the woodworking forums have a smattering of pros of various types throughout the membership, from furniture makers to jobbing carpenters who could well have done van fit-outs, so could give excellent advice on that front. Anyway, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ideally I would like to use finger joints, but without a table saw I'm stuck. However I could use a router.

Yes you can just as easily make finger joints/box joints with a router (generally using a router table<sup>1</sup>) as with a table saw. And as usual with the comparison, probably more safely.

Finger joints are awesome and they look great, however for overhead cabinets they are serious overkill. They are a great way to get approximately the strength of dovetails with all that interlocking wood and glue surface area, but this sort of strength is generally not needed except on standalone pieces which might be moved a lot, bumped into etc.

Obviously there's potential for the overheads in a van to be bumped into as well, but, since most van build-ins don't rely on finger joints and hold up perfectly fine it strongly suggests that sort of strength just isn't required....

> I've seen a lot of videos on keyed mitred joints, the ones that go all the way through. Where you get that nice contrast of wood.
>
> Then I've seen similar joints but made with through dowels.
>
> What are your thoughts with regard to ease and strength with these options?

This isn't a contest with regard to ease (dowels win comfortably as I'll get into below).

But whether one is stronger than the other is an open question because of the variables involved<sup>2</sup> and although there are comparative tests that include both options the results are not consistent. So we're left with what our guts tell us, and for one person that'll tell them the keys add more strength and for another that dowels are the winner.

Although I'm a big fan of dowels to be fair I think we must consider the strength contest a wash without more data<sup>3</sup>, but dowels still win hand down because of various advantages that go beyond the speed and simplicity. Here's an incomplete list of the advantages:

- For a start no jig or complex setup is required, you just drill a series of holes and glue in matching dowel and that's most of the work done. Plus it uses a tool that almost everyone has already, which is nice.
- The box doesn't need to be completely glued together before you drill for the through-dowels, which means you can work one corner at a time if you want to or it's convenient for any reason — say if you only have one or two corner clamps.
- Commercial dowelling can easily be found in most places and is generally cheap. Don't overlook bamboo skewers as a source of strong and thin dowelling material, especially valuable when working with thinner stock.
- If convenient or necessary, joinery dowels are very easily made in the workshop by various means, including using a very crude dowel maker if no other option is available (see Paul Sellers's [Poor man's dowel maker](https://paulsellers.com/2013/07/poor-mans-dowel-maker/)). And making short dowels suitable for joinery is a superb way to use up skinny *and* short offcuts that otherwise have little potential use except as kindling.
- Dowels don't have to rely mostly or entirely on glue strength because they don't have to go in perpendicular to the surface, but can be driven in dovetail fashion (also referred to as toenailing) like this: \ \ | / / or like this \ / \ / \ / which ads a mechanical advantage. With through-dowels this is *always* worth doing for added strength since it requires zero additional effort; align the angle along the axis of the second piece and there's almost zero risk of blowing out the side.

In case it's not obvious, since you're using mitred corners you can (and should) drive dowels in from both sides of each joint. Offset the hole patterns so they don't intersect!

---

<sup>1</sup> Doesn't have to be a formal router table, a sheet of plywood, MDF or even particleboard/chipboard with a hole drilled through, clamped to the edge of a table, can be perfectly adequate for many operations.

<sup>2</sup> The shape of keys, whether they're 'flat' or done at angles, the diameter and length of the dowels, the species used, of course the number of either and possibly also the spacing.

<sup>3</sup> Although with thinner material (under 1/2" / 13mm?) I don't think there is any chance dowelling isn't vastly stronger because there's so much less glue area possible for the keys and a limited amount on the mitres themselves.

Comment: wow that is a lengthy and well received reply. Thank you so much for your time in replying to this.  I was thinking to slightly over engineering it purely due to the vibrations of travel and yes it being knocked into etc.

Answer (score 0):

> What are your thoughts with regard to ease and strength with these options?

The two options I can think of for easy, attractive, strong miter joints are:

- **glue blocks:** Rip square or triangular hardwood strips from a board and glue them into the inside corners of the joint. The blocks add lots of glue area, making the joint much stronger, while still giving the clean external appearance of a simple miter joint.
- **lapped miter joint:** I was going to recommend lock miter joints until I remembered that you're using plywood, and the interlocking protrusions in a lock miter joint easily snap off when made in plywood. However, Infinity Tools offers a set of [lapped miter joint bits](https://www.infinitytools.com/blog/2015/06/18/go-ahead-lap-it-up-new-lapped-miter-bits#) that purport to have some of the same advantages of lock miters (strength and easy assembly), but which are meant to work well with sheet goods. I haven't tried them, but they look promising. Note, however, that the minimum material thickness is 1/2", so you'd have to use slightly thicker material than the 3/8" stuff you were planning to use.

Comment: Yes I did think about this.

Answer (score -1):

This [video experiment](https://youtu.be/CE147Ow7RmM) pitted a selection of joints against each other in terms of pounds of pressure against the joint at a 45 degree angle -- the clear winner was a mitre joint, with a spline mitre coming in second... further down the list was a dowel butt joint (the dowels being drilled into the grain of the inner butt piece).

The experiment is one measure of strength of the relative joins. I have my questions about the method -- if you're building cabinets, you have to consider where your force is going to be coming from. I'd guess the weight of whatever you place inside on the bottom would be a lateral force on that side, or perhaps the force of the box away from the side that's drilled into the side of the van.

You could try a similar experiment using plywood, apply force using weights or a clamp and find your answer. Share it with us if you do!

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. Because many people are reluctant to follow blind links please provide the source of any link you post, unless the link itself clearly self-identifies (as it might for example if it was from Popular Woodworking or Wood Magazine). In this case I know the link you used and I wouldn't have wanted to follow it inadvertently as, although this test was actually well conducted IMHO (better than some others), I've vowed never to visit any of his content again after he faked the results of linseed-soaked rags spontaneously combusting, for views and sponsorship.

Comment: Now that aside, this link is problematic as the basis of an Answer to the Question posed. because he used solid wood as the base material and the OP is planning on using plywood; the two materials present a *very* different picture re. the strength of the underlying glue joint. Just as important is the inherent strength/cohesiveness of the material itself (plywood often delaminating as part of its failure mode). *"the clear winner was a mitre joint"* Um, I remember the box joint doing noticeable better than the plain mitre!

Comment: Yes I've seen that link, and also quite a few others testing ply, pine, MDF etc etc. Thank you for your time though.